# Class-approved wet welding: the meaning of "Class" (and why capitalize?)

Tags: phrase-meaning, capitalization

A [quote](http://www.subseasolutions.com/about-us.php):

> With a dedicated staff situated globally, Subsea Global Solutions has revolutionized the methods of repair for ships; ship propellers, thrusters, ship seal, **Class approved wet welding**, and permanent shell plate repairs with cofferdams.

"Class approved wet welding" - what could it mean precisely? Approved by a [classification society](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_society) or complying with specifications for the execution of work typified into a particular class (class A welding, or class B welding, say)? And why is the word **class** capitalized?

P.S. A related question [was asked by me](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/197980/underwater-welding-proceduce-on-a-ship-approved-by-class-meaning) at ELU.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For welding, there are different well-defined classifications of welds based on what is being welded, so "Class" may be capitalized because it refers to a particular class from a specification.

For example:

> Quality assurance provisions for all weld classes are detailed in Section 7.0. Weld classes shall be chosen on the basis of the following definitions:
>   a. Class A (Flight or non flight) — Applies to welds in critical load bearing 
>   elements that are not fail-safe.

*[Process Specification for the Manual Arc Welding of Aluminum Alloy Hardware](http://mmptdpublic.jsc.nasa.gov/prc/7180g.pdf)*, NASA 2007

Comment: Thank you, Colleen! Would the meaning be lost without capitalization?

Comment: No, I don't think the meaning changes significantly. I've seen companies use it both capitalized and lowercase. Underwater or wet welding is the most difficult, so I believe this company capitalized it to emphasize their credentials.

Answer (score 3):

In the case of "wet welding" the reference is specific to underwater welding in the water rather than in a dry environment submerged in water, i.e. a cofferdam or habitat.

Class approval speaks to classification societies and their repair approval specifications, Lloyds of London, American Bureau of Shipping, Det Norse, etc.  These societies, of which there are 80 plus worldwide have a global membership called [IACS](http://www.iacs.org.uk/) (International Association of Classification Societies) and are responsible for the safety of life at sea and ship building practices.

Answer (score 1):

As you could probably guess from the context -- talking about repairing ships and ship parts -- and from the name, "wet welding" is a process for welding underwater.

I don't know what "Class approved" means here. From the fact that "Class" is capitalized I'd guess there's some recognized organization that hands out these approvals, but I couldn't find anything in a brief search. I'll leave that part of your question to anyone who, well, knows the answer.